# Weblogic Console not coming to login page

Tags: weblogic-10.x

When I try to launch the weblogic console page in my browser after starting weblogic using command prompt, the login page isn't coming up for a long time.

I see the "Deploying application for /console" message followed by a long sequence of "." (dot/period). This is going on for a long time.

I observed this message printed on the command prompt from where I launched the startWebLogic.cmd file

```
<Warning> <Socket> <BEA-000449> <Closing socket as
no data read from it during the configured idle timeout of 5 secs>"
```

Is this the reason for the console not coming up? If yes, how to resolve it?

Comment: Does the console ever come up? Do you get a 404 or 403 error? Any other errors in the `<domain>/server/<server name>/logs` files? If it ever does come up you can disable that deploy behavior like: http://redstack.wordpress.com/2009/07/14/how-to-disable-on-demand-deployment-of-weblogic-console-application/

Comment: Yes. It does come up. However, the time taken is way too long. Thanks for the link shared. It fixed my problem.

Comment: @display-name-is-missing , The link you shared solved my problem. Please post the above comment as an answer so that I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the console app is deploying extremely slow, you can change to following setting:

- Login to the WebLogic admin console
- Click your domain name link on the left hand side
- Open Configuration tab and General sub-tab
- Uncheck the box labeled `Enable on-demand deployment of internal applications`
- Save
- Activate changes